Positive recurrence of an infinite discrete time Markov chain on Z?
Stuck on this problem: consider an infinite state Markov chain representing a random walk on integers, where from any state i, the
chain moves to state i + 1 with probability p, remains in state i with probability q, and moves to state i − 1 with probability 1 − p - q. Let q = 0.1.
Then for p < 0.5, prove that this chain is positive recurrent.
Because all states communicate, I believe it suffices to find an explicit stationary distribution. However, I'm not sure if one exists, based on the recurrence relation from the balance equations and the convergence requirement.
